# Unable to create capture from file in Emgucv

Tags: .net, opencv, emgucv

```
if (_capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                _capture = new Capture("video1.mpg");
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {   //show errors if there is any
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

video1.mpg file is in bin folder. **I have converted an avi file to MPEG-1 format with any-video-converter.** 
But still this format is not working. I have tried **mencoder** also. but still same error.

```
Unable to create capture from video1.mpg
```

how to make it compatible with emgu `Capture`?

Comment: Your error doesn't match your code. ".mpg" and ".avi"

Comment: writing mistake. EDITED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Convert the video to i420 fromat.**

[Download this converter.](http://mplayerwin.sourceforge.net/downloads.html)

**Command to execute convertion:**

```
mencoder inputVideo.avi -ovc raw -vf format=i420 -o convertedVideo.avi
```

This convertedVideo.avi can be captured now.

Comment: I purchased mencoder. However when I click the mencoder exe file it the cmd open and closes really quickly. Also when I top the command above into the cmd it says it does not recognize mencoder. Where do I type this command to convert a file?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert your Vedio file in .avi format.and use some other tool to convert the required vedio file. there may be possibility that the tool which you are using right now is demo version that's why it may not covert it properly.. .and then try following code:

```
   string nameOfFile = @"D:\somefile.avi";// your vedio path
Capture _capture = new Capture(name);
      try
        {
            _capture = new Capture(nameOfFile);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {   //show errors if there is any
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```